# How to assert that the result from console is the same as expected?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have already implemented code and I have to unit test it. I have a Display() method that at the end is printing in the console. So to test it, I have to assert that the result printed in the console is the as expected. Here is the Display() method.

```
 public void Display(int[] playerPosition)
        {
            StringBuilder matrixAsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int row = 0; row < this.Rows; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < this.Cols; col++)
                {
                    if (playerPosition[1] == row && playerPosition[0] == col)
                    {
                        matrixAsStringBuilder.Append(this.PlayerSymbol);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        matrixAsStringBuilder.Append(this.matrix[row, col]);
                    }

                    if (col < this.Cols - 1)
                    {
                        matrixAsStringBuilder.Append(" ");
                    }
                }
                matrixAsStringBuilder.Append("\n");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(matrixAsStringBuilder.ToString());
        }
```

How can I verify that the result from console is my expectation. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you're better off rewriting this method to have it return a string, rather than console-writing it. That way you can assert the outcomevalue, plus you increase your methods extensibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. Let `Display` return a `String` and then print that string out to the console in a separate method. You know that `Console.WriteLine()` works so you just have to test your method that does the processing.

This will also be in line with general programming guidelines: let one method do one thing. It shouldn't both be processing the data and printing it out, not in the least because this curses at method naming: you call it "Display" but it does in fact a lot more than just displaying.